# Serializing AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtable

I am trying to serialize abstractTableModel and when im trying to save table content in file, that file is successfully saved but i guess it is always empty (or dont save it properly) because it's size is always 17KB, no matter if i save empty or filled table...

here is my GUI of appointment schedule table:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2qm3p8k.jpg

and here is my code... I hope it is not problem because it have some more lines...

```
public class TerminiPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Serializable {

static JPanel terminPanel;
static Calendar terminiCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
static int dan = terminiCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
static int mesec = terminiCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
static int godina = terminiCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String mesecIme;
static String izabraniDan;

JPanel buttonPanel;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JButton saveBtn;
static JTable table;

TerminiPanel(JPanel thisPanel) {
    super();
    this.terminPanel = thisPanel;
    this.terminPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    switch (Listener.monthChoose.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            mesecIme = "Januar";
            break;
        case 1:
            mesecIme = "Februar";
            break;
        case 2:
            mesecIme = "Mart";
            break;
        case 3:
            mesecIme = "April";
            break;
        case 4:
            mesecIme = "Maj";
            break;
        case 5:
            mesecIme = "Juni";
            break;
        case 6:
            mesecIme = "Juli";
            break;
        case 7:
            mesecIme = "Avgust";
            break;
        case 8:
            mesecIme = "September";
            break;
        case 9:
            mesecIme = "Oktobar";
            break;
        case 10:
            mesecIme = "Novembar";
            break;
        default:
            mesecIme = "Decembar";
            break;
    }

    String tb = "Zakazani za " + dan + "." + mesecIme + " " + Listener.yearChoose.getSelectedItem();
    TitledBorder titledBorder = new TitledBorder(tb);
    terminPanel.setBorder(titledBorder);

    ///////////// Mali panel za dugme "Sacuvaj"
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    saveBtn = new JButton("Sacuvaj");

        ////////// Listener za zakazivanje - cuvanje podataka iz tabele u file /////////////
    saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TerminiPanel.main(terminPanel); 
        }
    });
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    buttonPanel.add(saveBtn);

    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    table = new JTable(new TerminiTableModel());
    table.setRowHeight(25);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    terminPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    terminPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

        ///////////////////// prilikom klika na dan u kalendaru /////////////////////////
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    izabraniDan = e.getActionCommand();

    String tb = "Zakazani za " + izabraniDan + "." + mesecIme + " " + Listener.yearChoose.getSelectedItem();

    TitledBorder titledBorder = new TitledBorder(tb);
    terminPanel.setBorder(titledBorder);

    TerminiTableModel tp = null;

    try
      {
        System.out.println("Pocinjem ucitavanje fajla " + e.getActionCommand() + "" + (mesec + 1) + "" + Listener.yearChoose.getSelectedItem() + ".ser");
        FileInputStream fileIn =
                          new FileInputStream("" + e.getActionCommand() + "" + (mesec + 1) + "" + Listener.yearChoose.getSelectedItem() + ".ser");

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        tp = (TerminiTableModel) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println("Zavrsio . . . ");
       }catch(IOException i) {
           System.out.println("Nema fajla sa tim imenom . . . "); //ako nema fajla   TO DO  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

           //i.printStackTrace();
           return;
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
           System.out.println("TerminiPanel class not found");
           //c.printStackTrace();
           return;
       }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}

public static void main(JPanel terminPanel2) {
    TableModel tp = new TerminiTableModel().tableModel;
    try {
        if (izabraniDan == null)
            izabraniDan = Integer.toString(dan);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("" + izabraniDan + "" + (mesec + 1) + "" + godina + ".ser");

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        out.writeObject(tp);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Uspesno ste sacuvali zakazane pacijente za dan " + izabraniDan + "." + (mesec + 1) + "." + godina);

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }   
}

}
```

My AbstractTableModel is in other class, if it is needed I will upload it also...
I would like to know where i made mistake so it doesn't save my table content and also why it doesn't load even empty table after click on date that don't have saved file for itself...

Thx for help...

PS: I edited code... here is what i did, no errors now, but it dont do the job :-/

Comment: you are trying to serialize the entire GUI. instead, save only the contents of the table model and then load those...

Comment: Well, my table is in my JScrollPane and when i try to put it in public static void main(JPanel terminPanel2) instead of terminPanel2, it says there is an error...
How can i serialize only table and not GUI ?